# Resulting image color is not exactly what i passed

Tags: php, gd

I have a one color image and I want to change that color with GD library. Image is a PNG and I want to keep transparency as well. I have written following code that keeps transparency and changes color but resulting color is not the color that I used in imagefilter function.
For example if I pass 0,0,255 then resulting image color will be 194,194,255.

Please help me fixing this problem. Here is my code.

```
<?php
// first we will create a transparent image. an image that has no color.
$width = 294; $height=333;
$image = imagecreatetruecolor($width,$height); //black image of the specified width x height. 

imagealphablending($image, false);  // set blend mode to false.

$col=imagecolorallocatealpha($image,255,255,255,127); // fill color

imagefilledrectangle($image,0,0,$width,$height,$col); 

imagealphablending($image,true);


$shirt = imagecreatefrompng("primary_shirts/shirt.png");
imagesavealpha($shirt, true);
imagefilter($shirt, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);
imagefilter($shirt, IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE, 0,0,255);

imagecopy($image, $shirt, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height);

imagealphablending($image,true);
imagealphablending($image,false);
imagesavealpha($image,true);

if(imagepng($image, "primary_shirts/hello.png", 1)){
    echo "http://localhost/site/primary_shirts/hello.png";
}

imagedestroy($image);
imagedestroy($shirt);
?>
```

**EDIT: I m trying to colorize an image to blue color(0,0,255). This script colorize image but resulting image is not (0,0,255) instead it is (76,76,255). Why so?**

Comment: where's `header("Content-type: image/png");`?

Comment: what is `http://localhost/bxp-site/primary_shirts/hello.png` anyway?

Comment: i m on local host and saving image(hello.png) in a folder named primary_shirts

Comment: `if(imagepng($image, "primary_shirts/hello.png", 1)){
    echo "http://localhost/site/primary_shirts/hello.png";
}` what should this do?

Comment: I m trying to colorize an image to blue color(0,0,255). This script colorize image but resulting image is not (0,0,255) instead it is (76,76,255). Why so?

Comment: check http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorset.php

Answer (score 0):

```
if(imagepng($image, "primary_shirts/hello.png", 1)){
```

should be

```
if(imagepng($image, "primary_shirts/shirt.png", 1)){
```

?

And where's your `header("Content-type: image/png");`?

I don't know what the contents of hello.png nor shirt.png are. But try to stick to the [simplest example](http://www.php.net/manual/en/image.examples-png.php) (unless you're going to provide more info)

Answer (score 0):

```
$red = 0; $green = 204; $blue = 204;
$shirt = "primary_shirts/shirt.png";
$im = imagecreatefrompng ($shirt);
imagesavealpha($im, true);
imagefilter($im,IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);
if($im && imagefilter($im,IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE, $red-195, $green-195, $blue-195  ) )
{
    imagepng($im, 'primary_shirts/hello.png');
    echo "http://localhost/site/primary_shirts/hello.png";
}
```

it seems IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE does not really do what php.net says. It in fact subtracts an image color from what you pass it. Above code is exactly doing what i want it to do so far.